# PHP string not formatted as valid XML

Tags: php, xml, oracle, xmltype

I have created a string that I want to pass to an Oracle database as a CLOB and then I run `XMLTYPE.createxml` on the CLOB, but when I do this it keeps giving the error `LPX-00007: unexpected end-of-file encountered`.

I've checked everything and can't seem to see whats going on, is the string invalid XML or am I missing something!?

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<location>
    <id>23451</id>
    <code>2</code>
    <date>20151217</date>
</location>
<location>
    <id>23452</id>
    <code>3</code>
    <date>20151217</date>
</location>
<location>
    <id>23453</id>
    <code>3</code>
    <date>20151217</date>
</location>
```

Comment: Root Element is missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make your XML well-formed you need single root element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
  <location>
    <id>23451</id>
    <code>2</code>
    <date>20151217</date>
  </location>
  <location>
    <id>23452</id>
    <code>3</code>
    <date>20151217</date>
  <location>
  <location>
    <id>23453</id>
    <code>3</code>
    <date>20151217</date>
  </location>
</root>
```

Comment: Always the simple things, been looking at it for an hour.

Comment: @llanato Protip: Use XML validator (there are online version too) 